# Update Salesforce record via API from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, salesforce

I have successfully authenticated Google apps script to salesforce and can query records in Salesforce from Google apps script.

My next hurdle is to update a single record in Salesforce from Google apps script. Here is what I have so far:

I started with code from [Patch payload question in Google Script REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AOrIAM)

```
function updateQuoteUrls() {  
  //custom object name i360__Quote__c

  var quoteId = "ABC123"; // ID
  var folderUrl = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/DEFXXX";  // Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c
  var sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XYZ123";  // Pricing_Sheet_URL__c

  var instanceUrl = "https://na53.salesforce.com";

  var queryUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/"+MyId+"?_HttpMethod=PATCH";

  var payload = "{\"Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c\":\" + folderUrl + "\;\"Pricing_Sheet_URL__c\":\" + sheetUrl + \"}";

  var headers = 
      { 
        "Authorization" : "OAuth "+accessToken,
        "Content-type" : "application/json"
      };

  var options =
      {
        headers : headers,
        method : "POST",
        payload : payload
      };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl, options);

}
```

Questions: How do I access the custom object and specific record? I did not define MyId. Is that the record id?

Here's my updated code: (closer, but still not working yet.)

```
function updateQuoteUrls3() {
  var service = getService();
  var accessToken = service.getAccessToken();
  var quoteId = "a1Gf200000GkZex"; // ID
  var folderUrl = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/DEFXXX";  // Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c
  var instanceUrl = "https://na53.salesforce.com";
  var queryUrl = "/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/i360__Quote__c/" + quoteId + ".json";
  var payload = {
    "Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c": folderUrl,
    "Pricing_Sheet_URL__c": sheetUrl
  };
  var headers = {
    //"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, // Double-check if you should use Bearer or OAuth. (I use Bearer.)
    "Authorization": "OAuth " + accessToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "patch",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  var url = instanceUrl + queryUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return response; // HTTPresponse - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the record ID for the Account that you're trying to update.

Comment: I recommend simplifying your life by creating `payload` as a regular JS object, and then stringifying it with `JSON.stringify()`. If you do that, you won't have to do all the string concatenation and character escaping that you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value for `MyId` should, as you correctly assumed, be the record ID. You can get that easily from your original query by simply including `Id` in the `SELECT` statement.

You don't actually need to append your URL with `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` since you can specify PATCH as the method in the request (as listed in the [advanced params documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)).

What you do need to do is append `.json` to the end of your request, as rather cryptically indicated in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_usage_rest_resources.htm).

I recommend simplifying your life by creating `payload` as a regular JS object, and then stringifying it with `JSON.stringify()`. If you do that, you won't have to do all the string concatenation and character escaping that you're currently doing.

Ostensibly, your code could then be modified to:

```
function updateQuoteUrls(recordId) {
  var quoteId = "ABC123"; // ID
  var folderUrl = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/DEFXXX";  // Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c
  var sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XYZ123";  // Pricing_Sheet_URL__c
  var instanceUrl = "https://na53.salesforce.com";
  var queryUrl = "/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/" + recordId + ".json";
  var payload = {
    "Google_Drive_Folde_URL__c": folderUrl,
    "Pricing_Sheet_URL__c": sheetUrl
  };
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, // Double-check if you should use Bearer or OAuth. (I use Bearer.)
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "patch",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  var url = instanceUrl + queryUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return response; // HTTPresponse - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response
}
```

Comment: Thank you Diego, stringify does indeed make it simpler and cleaner. I am new to APIs, so please forgive my ignorance. I am now getting an error [{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}],  somehow I am not passing the right session ID.

Comment: @JasonPhillips That relates to your `accessToken`. Use the same authentication you were using with your query request, whether that be `"OAuth " + accessToken` or `"Bearer " + accessToken`.

Comment: I did change it back to Bearer. Since you helped with the first issue I was having, I closed the question and asked a [new one] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617545/oauth2-401-invalid-session-id-when-accessing-salesforce-from-google-apps-script). Can you take a look at it for me?